# How to disable and showing another button text untill the button is loaded in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

How to disable the button untill the button is loaded in AngularJS?

This is my directive for  indicate data loading status, and disable button untill $http request is processed.
But the problem is when i reload the page the button will automatically disable and reloaded.How to restrict that?
One more issue.

If I have two more button in the same page when i submit one of that button the entire button will disable and showing loading...

I need two things

1. When a page is loaded the the other buttons are not disable not showing loading...I want to disable the entire page and currrent submit button should be shown loading...
2. if one button is submit the other butttons are not showing loading...

This is my code script.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  $scope.save = function() {

    $http.pendingRequests.length = 1;
    $timeout(function() {
      $http.pendingRequests.length = 0;
    }, 1000);


  };

 $scope.submit = function() {

    $http.pendingRequests.length = 1;
    $timeout(function() {
      $http.pendingRequests.length = 0;
    }, 1000);


  };

});


myApp.directive("disableonrequest", function($http,$timeout) 
{
    return function(scope, element, attrs) 
    {
        scope.$watch(function() 
        {
            return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
        }, function(request)
        {
            if (!request) 
            {               
                element.attr('disabled', false);
                element.html("<span >" + attrs.notloading + "</span>");

            } 
            else 
            {
                element.attr('disabled', true);
                element.html("<span >" + attrs.loading + "</span><i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin'></i>");       

            }
        });
    }
});
```

view.html

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="save()" loading="Loading..." notloading="Save" disableonrequest></button>
  <button ng-click="submit()" loading="Loading..." notloading="Submit" disableonrequest></button>
</body>
```

When i click on each button both button will disable and show loading...

how to restrict that?

I want to disable the entire page when a button is clicked and submitted button should be shown loading...

Please help me. I am new in Angular JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your `$watch` depends on the global variable `$http.pendingRequests`. And when the value of the variable changes, then angular starts change function for the two directives.

To avoid this, use different variables to store values loading. Example can watch [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/v45z4yz1/)

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  $scope.saving = false;
  $scope.submiting = false;
  $scope.save = function() {

    $http.pendingRequests.length = 1;
     $scope.saving = true;
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.saving = false;
      $http.pendingRequests.length = 0;
    }, 1000);


  };

  $scope.submit = function() {
   $scope.submiting = true;
    $http.pendingRequests.length = 1;
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.submiting = false;
      $http.pendingRequests.length = 0;
    }, 1000);


  };

});


myApp.directive("disableonrequest", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      notloading: "@",
      loading: "@",
      proccess:"=",
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('proccess', function(request) {
        console.log(request,element);
        if (!request) {
          element.attr('disabled', false);
          element.html("<span >" + scope.notloading + "</span>");
        } else {
          element.attr('disabled', true);
          element.html("<span >" + scope.loading + "</span><i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin'></i>");
        }
      });
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="save()" loading="Loading..." proccess="saving" notloading="Save" disableonrequest></button>
  <button ng-click="submit()" loading="Loading..." proccess="submiting" notloading="Submit" disableonrequest></button>
</body>
```

### UPDATED

Solution with block all page.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/uc9w8xey/)

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  $scope.pendingRequests = $http.pendingRequests;
  $scope.save = function() {
    $http.pendingRequests.length++;
    $timeout(function() {
      $http.pendingRequests.length--;
    }, 1000);


  };

  $scope.submit = function() {
    $http.pendingRequests.length++;
    $timeout(function() {
      $http.pendingRequests.length--;
    }, 1000);


  };

});


myApp.directive("blockWhileLoad", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace:true,
    transclude:true,
    scope: {
      proccess: "=",
    },
    template:'<div><div ng-transclude></div><div ng-class="{\'blocker\':proccess>0}"></div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    },
  }
});
```

```css
.errors {
  color: maroon
}
.blocker
{
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px; 
  right: 0px; 
  z-index: 1038;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <fieldset ng-disabled="pendingRequests.length>0">
    <input />
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>

  <block-while-load proccess="pendingRequests.length">
    <input />
    <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
  </block-while-load>
</body>
```

Comment: Sir ok.. Thanyou your code is awsome but how to disable my entire page on that time.because while loading submit button i need to disable entire thing.otherwise user can able to click save button rit?

Comment: How to disable that entire page while loading,otherwise user can able to click another button how it posiible any remedis

Comment: It's bad practice to block all page. If you need this, you may include all your buttons, inputs in `fieldset` and then disabled `fieldset`.

Comment: @Stephan. Your coding style is entirely good. I think you are a  teacher.Really Understandable for each and every part and  your suggestion also.Its a good practice I think God bless you..Can you give me your mailid.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, angularjs use promises and the $http service extend $q, so you can use promises with that service.

From: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
//Before the request, set element as loading
    element.attr('disabled', true);
    element.html("<span >" + attrs.loading + "</span><i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin'></i>"); 

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/someUrl'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // when the http is fully loaded, set visible
        element.attr('disabled', false);
        element.html("<span >" + attrs.notloading + "</span>");
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // show an error message or just put the button available again
        element.attr('disabled', false);
        element.html("<span >" + attrs.notloading + "</span>");
      });
```